# Yii 2 сохранять NULL а не пустую строку

Tags: yii2

Каким образом можно сохранять поля как NULL а не как ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на вскидку можно ручками указать default

```
              [['url'], 'default',  'value' => null],
```